# Wordpress Custom Progress Bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, progress-bar

Is anyone familiar with Wordpress and the [Custom Progress Bar plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-progress-bar)?

I'm using this progress bar and have an HTML button that, when pressed, should add 10% to the progress bar - it should only add 60% to the progress bar the first time it's pressed, after that it should do nothing.

What I've written isn't working and I feel as if I've hit a wall. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here's my code for reference:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      document.getElementByClassName(".progressbar").style.width = 60 % ;
    }
  </script>
</head>
<div>
  <button id="selector" onclick="myFunction()">Complete</button>
</div>
<div>[progressbar_simple class="progressbar"]
</div>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) is not used properly. Notice the spelling carefully.

You don't have to use the dot before the classname. Just `"progressbar"` will suffice.

Also this `returns an an array-like object of all child elements which have all of the given class names.` To target a particular element, use the index of the element.

Finally, the width value to should be inside quotes

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      document.getElementsByClassName("progressbar")[0].style.width= "60%";
    }
  </script>
</head>
<div>
  <button id="selector" onclick="myFunction()">Complete</button>
</div>
<div>[progressbar_simple class="progressbar"]
</div>

</html>
```

Comment: Hareesh, 

I tried the code you suggested and I see this in the console: 

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined"